# Which character is Ctrl+Backspace?

Tags: passwords, special-characters

There are several places that you can enter this character by typing ctrl-backspace, including windows loggon password.

Which character is this and can I use it in a password?

Comment: Using the standard 94, readable, ascii digits (33-127) in a random 10 digit password a brute force method running at 1000 iterations per second would take approximately 12 times the age of the universe to break. If we assume a quintillion attempts per second but up the length of your password to 12 it would still take over a month to crack. So my question is why?

Comment: I am accidentally typing this character every time I enter wrong character in the password. The answer to your question is "curiosity" :)

Comment: The perfect answer! I think it's just multiple backspace keys so ascii 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on the control being used.  Assuming a regular text box, that's character code 127 (0x7f), legacy mapping for the DEL control code.  Displays as a rectangle since there's no Unicode glyph for it.  This will not necessarily reproduce well, a Rich Edit control will interpret it as a "delete to begin of line" control key.  Very unlikely you'll be able to enter such a password at a web page prompt for example.